# flex RE for alphanumerics also prints #$@

Tags: c, regex, visual-studio-2008, flex-lexer

i'm trying to make a lexical analyser(on VS2008 using flex and bison) who will only pick alphanumerics(john4323snow) and number( 1234 ). The problem is that at the end of the alphanumerics and numbers it also puts characters like #$%@. I don't understand why. thank you for your time!

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int k;
%}

%option noyywrap

%%
0|[1-9]* {
        k = atoi(yytext);
        printf("Found the Number %d", k); 
        }
 [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {printf("Found the Identifier %s", yytext); }
%%
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char infile[20];
    strcpy(infile, argv[1]);
    yyin = fopen(infile, "r");
    if(yyin == NULL)
    {
        printf("open failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        yylex();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings that do not fall into any pattern, the string is printed to the standard output.

So be changed as follows

```
%%
0|[1-9]* {
        k = atoi(yytext);
        printf("Found the Number %d", k); 
        }
 [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {printf("Found the Identifier %s\n", yytext); }
. ;
"\n" ;
%%
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answear i've stuck in this for over an hour now. Anyway the strings that do not fall into any pattern are also printed to the standard output, so i have to put these 2 extra lines in every code that prints the output on the screen? That also means that instead of printf if i would put the yytext in a new file the 2 extra lines won't be needed? Thnx again i can move on finally!

Comment: @captainmonk It is two lines that you have added to the end will not do anything if it does not match. 
I think that there is a need to add these two lines in the same way such a case. 
The action part is also needed when performing such error display rather than simply discarded.